# New Constructor.apply(null, args) - возможно?

Tags: javascript

```
var test = new Test.apply(null, args);
```

Возможно ли это воссоздать в коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:]

```
var test = new (Test.bind.apply(Test, [null].concat(args)))
```

Это всё последствия bind + apply, при помощи которых мы каррируем конструктор и получаем новый, т.к. bind внутри себя [наследует prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_JavaScript_1.5/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B/Function/bind) оригинала, то на вы выходе, мы получили наследника от Test с уже постановленными параметрами. При последующем вызове new и передаче дополнительных параметров, они буду добавлены в конец, как и полагается при использовании bind, вот пример каррирования попроще:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console, "Logger:");
log(1, 2, 3); // Logger: 1 2 3
```

---

**UPD**

```
var test = Object.create(Test.prototype);
Test.apply(test, args);
```

**ES6**

```
var test = new Test(...args);
```

Comment: Сегодня я уже такое не осилю))) Если не пойму завтра, то спрошу, а если пойму, то уточню. Спасибо!

Comment: @RubaXa, а можете вот это объяснить?

      new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Array, [null].concat([1,2,3])))(4,5,6)
      // Array [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]

Comment: @RubaXa, прочел пару статей и ВРОДЕ разобрался. Хоть это без подкрепления на практике, звучит громко, но все же. Но есть момент с непониманием [null]. Почему если не добавить null, то первый элемент исчезает?

Comment: Ответ в реализации самого `bind`, первым аргументом он получает контекст, но в случае с `apply`, он нам неважен, поэтому и передаем «что угодно», например `null`.

Comment: @vas, добавил ещё один вариант через `Object.create`.

Comment: @RubaXa, Спасибо! А когда ES6 вступит в силу?

Comment: @vas, на самом деле уже сейчас можно, просто через [трансляторы][1], например, [я][3] использую :] и не только, [Ember][2] недавно перевели все исходники на es6.

[1]: https://github.com/termi/es6-transpiler
[2]: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js
[3]: https://github.com/RubaXa/Ply/tree/master/src

Comment: Можно ещё добавить, что Ваш первый вариант при 100000 итерациях выполняется приблизительно за 3000мс, а вариант с Object.create, 250мс.  


1) http://jsfiddle.net/fcupmpg4/ 3000мс  
2) http://jsfiddle.net/3wmfwt3h/ 200мс

Comment: @vas, отличное дополнение. Но вот вам на заметку [сервис для тестов на производительность][1] http://jsperf.com/object-create-bind-aply

[1]: http://jsperf.com/